# Lenovo Ideapad 700 15ISK: How do I enable booting from CD/DVD and USB drives?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, boot, lenovo-laptop

I want to install Ubuntu on my laptop which is on a bootable DVD

How can I enable booting from DVD and start to install Ubuntu ?[image]

Comment: Set ATAPI CD as first boot priority device. Save changes and exit bios (F10)

Comment: @Moab thanks and what about if I wanna boot from USB drive?

Comment: set "USB HDD" to first place.